# How do I make the user go to a new page (with the post description) when an individual post is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

[example posts on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNW9G.png)
I have a list of posts on my homepage, and when a user clicks on it, I want to show the detailed post (on a new page). I am not looking for the code here- I just want some help figuring out how it would be done.
The posts are saved in a test table in a mySQL database. When a user clicks on a single post, I want to show them a new page (I will just use eventListener to show a newPage.html or something) with the description.
Here's where it got tricky, I want the post descriptions to load dynamically so I don't have to go in and make individual HTML files for each post.
Here's what I've done so far:
(1) The posts on the homepage are rendered from the MySQL database- I just created a new div(className="singlePost") and added the title & description from the database into that.
(2) Added an eventListener to each div so that when it's clicked, the div element is logged to the console & used location.href to point the user to a blank page (newPage.html).
(3) What I cannot figure out is how to pass the content of each div to the blank page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks:)

```
//the code is pretty confusing but hope it helps
//in node server.js

app.get('/showposts', (req,res) => {
    console.log('will shows all posts in database');
    connection.query(`select * from test`,
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log('got data from database');
            res.send(results)

        }
    )
})

//in the main.js file
document.addEventListener(
    'DOMContentLoaded',
    () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/showposts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // console.log(data);
                for (i in data) {
                    // console.log(data[i]);
                    singlePost = document.createElement('div');
                    singlePost.className = 'singlePost';
                    titleTextNode = document.createTextNode(data[i].title);
                    descriptionTextNode = document.createTextNode(data[i].description);
                    postHeading = document.createElement('h2');
                    postHeading.appendChild(titleTextNode);
                    singlePost.appendChild(postHeading);
                    singlePost.appendChild(descriptionTextNode);
                    allPosts.appendChild(singlePost);
                    // console.log(postHeading);
                    // console.log(singlePost);
                    clickableSinglePost = document.getElementsByClassName('singlePost');
                }

                for (let k = 0 ; k < clickableSinglePost.length; k++) {
                    clickableSinglePost[k].addEventListener(
                        'click',
                        () => {
                            console.log(clickableSinglePost[k]);
                            location.href = "http://localhost:4000/singlePost.html";
                        } 
                    ) 
                 }
```

Comment: Please include your code so we can give specific suggestions. [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user1599011 I've just added the code. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: You neglected to add your html, which is kind of important too. I think I'd just make each `div` a link (`a` tag) with the record id and pull the record detail on the new page.

Comment: Typically, you would append a query string value to your details page url:  singlePost.html?id=100   And then the page would query the db for the matching post. You could also do all this in one page, i.e., show the list when there is no id or details when id provide.

Comment: Hi user1599011, @Yogi thanks for the answer :)
I am still very new to js, so while I do understand some parts, I don't really understand much to implement it on my own.
This had me confused for nearly two days now, and I just realized something like a template engine exists solely for that purpose. I just found net ninja videos on ejs, so I am going to stick with that for now. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a view engine- ejs with Node.js